# Como usar um plugin cordova no meu ionic 3?

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Preciso implementar no meu aplicativo ionic o seguinte plugin:

[https://github.com/boltex/cordova-plugin-powermanagement&xid=17259,15700019,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700191,15700201,15700214,15700230&usg=ALkJrhg2u9afy7Kktp6dTGNpjb2uPGlDvA](http://Power%20Management)

Porém não consigo chama-lo no meu arquivo ts.

Tentei algo como:

```
window.plugins.powerManagement();
```

porém recebo:

> property plugins does not exist on type "Window"

Tem alguma forma que eu possa acessar esse plugin?

Já adicionei ele através:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/boltex/cordova-plugin-powermanagement.git
```

Mas, e agora?

Answer (score 0):

Pra quem se interessar, eu consegui acessar as propriedades desse plugin através da seguinte forma:

```
  (<any>window).powerManagement.dim();
  (<any>window).powerManagement.setReleaseOnPause(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

Os plugins do cordova somente são acessados através de um dispositivo... Ou seja, se você estiver testando através do navegador não será possível acessá-lo..

Na [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) pesquise sobre a propriedade `ready` acredito que resolverá seu problema.

Comment: Não era o que eu precisava.

Comment: já consegui, respondi minha propria pergunta